# How can I get a two digit week number from moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
var currentYear = moment().isoWeekYear().toString();
var currentWeek = moment().isoWeek().toString();
var endYear = moment().add(24, 'weeks').isoWeekYear().toString();
var endWeek = moment().add(24, 'weeks').isoWeek().toString();
```

This gives me `201734 - 20186` but I need `201734 - 201806` (the last 06). [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kkz0wty/).

I can of course check if week is < 10 and add a 0 to the string. But is there a way to format this using moment.js?

I tried using `var currentWeek = moment().isoWeek().format('ww').toString()` but that didn't work well.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#week-year-week-and-weekday-tokens

Comment: Yes, I know it has the `.format()` function and I've tried it. But it can't be used on `.isoWeek()`.

Comment: Why would it `GGGGWW` will return an ISO year and week

Comment: Doh! 've been trying `.isoWeekYear().format('YYYYWW)` when all it takes is  `moment().format('YYYYWW)`. Thnks :)  *face palm*

Comment: @RolandStarke - indeed, the norm is to use `YYYY` for years, even in ISO week dates, but moment uses `GGGG` for ISO week year for some reason. Most of the time `YYYY` will do the same thing, I think it's just edge cases, leap year and stuff that `GGGG` is a little different, don't really know ?

Comment: only a combination of `GGGGWW` or `YYYYww` makes sense i think. you will see the difference here for example: `moment('2017-01-01').format('GGGG WW') === '2016 52'` and `moment('2017-01-01').format('YYYY ww') === '2017 01'`

Answer (score 4):

Use this to get Week Number in two digit: `moment(new Date()).format('WW')`.